# Modem Question - PPPoE and PPPoA

Tags: windows, networking, internet, modem

What's the difference between PPPoE and PPPoA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPPoA (PPP over ATM):
ADSL access via Point-to-Point Protocol (aka Dial-Up Networking). The "FastAccess ADSL" icon is located in the Dial-Up Networking folder. The user authenticates with userid and password, then connects. This is similar to dialup except no actual dialing takes place. Only available with the PCI or USB modems (or various unsupported alternative modems and routers).

PPPoE (PPP over Ethernet):
Another dial-up type connection method. PPPoE client software is from NTS (or various unsupported alternatives). The icon is typically located in a NTS EnterNet 300 folder. (As of EnterNet 1.34, integration with DUN is also possible.) Username, password and then connect as with PPPoA. Note that an additional layer of software is involved here.

Comment: Windows XP and above supports PPPoE without any additional software.